# What type is this Value: [B@44952d40?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, inputstream

i have an input stream and when i display the value of this stream, i get the following output
 [B@44952d40

What type is this value ?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[128];  // buffer store for the stream
int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
bytes =  mmInStream.read(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you display the value of your buffer variable in the following way:

```
System.out.println(buffer);
```

Since buffer is an array and it doesn't override `toString()` method, it displays some weird string which is in fact memory location of your array. You will find the same output if you try to print on console an object which inherits `toString()` method from `Object` To display the real content of your array you need to either iterate through it or use `Arrays.toString(buffer)`